# getting jest to transpile outside of src directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I have a monorepo setup where the project running tests is trying to load a file from outside the current working directory.

Directory structure

```
root
 mainApp
   src...
 library
   greetings.js
```

Within greetings.js

```
export  const greetings = "hello World!"
```

Every time I try to import from greetings.js in my mainApp test files

```
//mainApp.test.js
import {greetings} from "../../greetings.js";
```

I get error from Jest in console

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

One solution in the following url is to add .babelrc to library folder
https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/455

I have quite a few libraries and adding .babelrc to each one isn't that clean. Is there any other / better way of achieving this.

I have even tried to add the following within setUp.js file for jest

```
require('babel-register')({
  plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs'],
  presets: ['env']
});
```

But jest is still failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Many Thanks

Comment: How is your jest configuration inside your package and your babel configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6053#issuecomment-383597952).

Rename .babelrc to babel.config.js and export your config instead.

*babel.config.js*
`module.exports = {}`

Answer (score 0):

In my case `babel-jest` could not find it's configuration file, this could be fixed by configuring the `transform` property in the `Jest configuration`.

Example for setting the `babel-jest configFile` property explicitly for `babel-jest`:

```js
transform: {
 '^.+\\.[jt]sx?$': [
   'babel-jest', { configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/babel.config.js') }
  1] 
},
```